# iframe load event not working in ie6

Tags: jquery

iframe load event in jQuery is not working in IE6

```
var iframe = this.iframe;
iframe.load(function(){


});
```

Comment: What is the context of this code? What is `this` in this case?

Comment: Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What are you trying to accomplish? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get ("it's not working" is not very informative)? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting?

Comment: Sorry, your question makes no sense.. you can't have `this.iframe` if jquery doesn't know what `this` is...

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed the `this.iframe` - i think you want:

```
var iframe = $('#iframe-ID-or-Class');
iframe.load(function() {
   //executable code
}
```

Comment: this.iframe = 
   $('<iframe name="' + name + '" id="ifrm"></iframe>')
            
    .css('display', 'none')
    .appendTo('body');

Comment: for ajax file upload.i am using jquery.ajax_upload.0.6.js, iframe.load() is called from onSubmit() event of ajax_upload.js

Comment: Please include all this in your question, people won't read EVERY comment to see all your code...